# Why don't I get a compilation error when casting a List to a MultiKeyMap?

Tags: java, casting

I've just run into a piece of code that casts [a `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) into [a `MultiKeyMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html) to call a method that takes a `MultiKeyMap` as argument:

```
someMethod ((MultiKeyMap) myList);
```

Where `myList` is a `List`.

Of course, it throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Why doesn't it show a compilation error or at least a warning "Type safety: Unchecked cast" as when trying to cast a `Collection` into a `Map`? Both types have nothing in common.

Comment: If you tried your example with an array list as opposed to a list(interface) you would get your expected compiler error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a compilation error, because there could be a `List` implementation that also happens to be a `MultiKeyMap`:

```
public MyHybrid extends MultiKeyMap implements List {
  // implement stuff
}
```

I'm not saying that it's a good idea, but the type system doesn't prevent it. Therefore the cast is allowed by the compiler.

The reason it's not an unchecked cast is because the target type has no generic type parameter (i.e. there's no `MultiKeyMap<K,V>`).

Comment: So you can always cast an interface into anything you want? It never occurred to me.

Comment: @LuisSep: yes, you can. Any cast that *could theoretically* succeed at runtime is allowed by the compiler.